# ST1S10 step-down regulator - can I drive the EN pin from the voltage divider?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, undervoltage

The [ST1S10 step-down regulator](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00169322.pdf) has an INHibit (active low) / ENable (high) input terminal, like many other DC-DC regulators.

I'd like to use it for an UVLO function. I initially thought of matching a voltage divider in a way that my battery cut-off voltage is at the high-low transition level of the EN pin of ST1S10. In the datasheet I can see though that the Vmax for OFF is 0.4V and Vmin for ON is 1.2.

What happens between 0.4V - 1.2V? Is that the hysteresis that I can rely on or is that an unknown state?

Answer (score 1):

0.4V and 1.2V are just the guaranteed limits. The typical threshold is around 0.75V, but it is strongly temperature dependent (see figure 12 in the datasheet).

You need an external comparator and voltage reference. Depending on the input voltage range and detection threshold required, a voltage supervisor IC might do the job (eg. [TC54VC](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=TC54)). 
However you may find that the regulator turns back on when the load is removed and battery voltage 'bounces back', in which case you will need a circuit with more hysteresis or a lockout function.

Comment: Thanks! TC54 looks to be a good choice, it's extremely easy to use and can drive directly a step-down enable/disable terminal. The problem might be the bouncing. There is other device I found: LMP7300 (http://www.ti.com/product/lmp7300) seems to do have a controlled hysteresis. The only problem is the availability of that chip in my country, ordering hobbyist quantities from Digikey or Mouser is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8l8S2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When Vin is low, Q1 is OFF and R3 keeps INH pin at logic low, shutting down the IC. When Vin is sufficiently high to overcome the Zener voltage of DZ1
Q1 begins turning ON, eventually shorting INH pin to Vs, allowing the IC to start operating.

Full disclosure: this is an adaptation of the UVLO schematic found in the datasheet of the [TI LM2596 switching regulator IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf) (figure 8-2), which has an active-low enable pin.

Of course you need to adapt the values to your situation, especially DZ1 Zener voltage. If Vin is low-ish, you would need low-voltage Zeners, which haven't got a very abrupt characteristics, so this circuit may not have very sharp thresholds. For Zeners with voltages above ~7V the situation improves.

**EDIT**

The following are the results of an LTspice simulation of that circuit, showing its behavior (you didn't state the nominal input voltage value, so I made some assumptions):

[image]

As you can see from the following graph, as long as the input voltage is above about Vz+1V, the INH pin is essentially shorted to Vin, allowing the chip to work.

[image]